# Reach data from Fragment_a for Fragment_b

Tags: java, android-fragments, fragment, android

I'm already red the android.developer page about Fragments, but what I need is:Fragment_A has an EditText and Fragment_B only a Button. When I press the button, i want make a Toast, within the EditText's data.

How can i do that? Thanks for helping.

MainActivity:

```
package rs.sqllogin.androidloginsql;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etUser, etPass;
    Button btnLogin;

    String username, password;
    // creat httpclient as the form container
    HttpClient httpclient;
    // httpPost method
    HttpPost httppost;
    // create an array list for the input data to be sent
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    // create a httpResponse and HttpEntity
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialise();

    }

    private void initialise() {
        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gomb le lett nyomva",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (etUser.getText().toString().equals("")
                || etPass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter some Data!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            new HttpAsyncTask().execute();

        }

    }

    public String POST() {

        // Create a new deafult httpclient
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Create a new HTTP Post with URL
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/checklogin.php");

        username = etUser.getText().toString();
        password = etPass.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        String str = "";

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            str = convertInputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("Catch1", "ClientProtocolE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("Catch2", "IllegalStatementE");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Catch3", "IOExpection");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;

    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return POST();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result.toString().equals("true")) {

                MyFragmentAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());
                ViewPager p = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                p.setAdapter(adapter);
                p.setCurrentItem(MyFragmentAdapter.NUM_ITEMS - 2);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Helytelen bejelentkezes!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The onPostExecute hangling the UI..

MyFragmentAdapter.java:

```
package rs.sqllogin.androidloginsql;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new FragmentOne());
        fragments.add(new FragmentTwo());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        return fragments.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

}
```

FragmentOne.java:

```
package rs.sqllogin.androidloginsql;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new FragmentOne());
        fragments.add(new FragmentTwo());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        return fragments.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

}
```

FragmentTwo.java:

```
package rs.sqllogin.androidloginsql;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    public static final String TAG = "FragmentTwo";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragmenttwo, null);
        Button btnSend = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);



        return v;


    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access anything from one fragment to another, you can create its static instance like below-

```
private static FragmentOne fragmentOne;

    public static FragmentOne getInstance() {
        if (fragmentOne == null) {
            fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
        }
        return fragmentOne;
    }

//you have edit text
public EditText myEditText;
```

Now in second fragment, you can access it by-

```
FragmentOne.getInstance().myEditText
```

Comment: Used your code, and got an exception. The First part of the code I used in FragmentOne.java, and in the FragmentTwo.java, within the onClick I got the problem, at this line 'String data = FragmentOne.getInstance().myEditText.getText().toString();'It is valid to use this? Sry for the noob questions...

Comment: what exception u got?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Then check what is null. Check if your edit text is properly initialized or not, if it is initialized then is has text or not?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why `EditText` and `Button` are in different `Fragments`?

I think that this is a more design issu than programming problem.

The Fragment should contain autonomous part of UI (e. g. form). Each fragment should know as little as possible about another Fragment.

If you really have to display a `Toast` when submitting do it in the `Activity`. 
Add a listener in Fragment_B:

```
public static interface FragmentBListener
{
   void onSubmit();
{
```

In `Fragment_B`

```
private FragmentBListener mListener;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity)
    try{
        mListener = (FragmentBListener) activity;
    }
    catch( ClassCastException e )
    {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity must iimplement FragmentBListener!");
    }

}
```

In `FragmentA` add method

```
public String getSubmitedText()
{
    return mEditTextInstance.getText().toString;
}
```

imlement your `FragmentBListener` in your `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onSubmit()
{

    String toastMessage = mFragmentA.getSubmitedText();
    //show Toast
}
```

Comment: I would like to use around 3-4 Fragments, every Fragment has some EditText, and at the last Fragment I will send the EditText's content with the Button. That why I made the UI like this. :) Ill try your code, thank you for helping!